# Using the REST API with PHP - Redmine

Tags: php, rest, redmine

The API I'm using is here:

```
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_php
```

Code: (if link not available)

```
<?php
require_once ('ActiveResource.php');

class Issue extends ActiveResource {
    var $site = 'http://username:password@192.168.199.129:3000/';
    var $request_format = 'xml'; // REQUIRED!
}

// create a new issue
$issue = new Issue (array ('subject' => 'XML REST API', 'project_id' => '1'));
$issue->save ();
echo $issue->id;

// find issues
$issues = $issue->find ('all');
for ($i=0; $i < count($issues); $i++) {
    echo $issues[$i]->subject;
}

// find and update an issue
$issue->find (1);
echo $issue->subject;
$issue->set ('subject', 'This is the new subject')->save ();
// update status
$issue->set ('status_id', 2)->save();

// delete an issue
$issue->find (1);
$issue->destroy ();
?>
```

I'm trying to use this API to access Redmine database and get some issues which has no one assigned to it.

Here's a example of a custom method (as seen in ActiveResource.php usage).

```
// custom method
$songs = $song->get ('by_year', array ('year' => 1999));
```

Finally, my code:

```
require_once ('ActiveResource.php');


class Issue extends ActiveResource {
    var $site = 'root:12345@localhost/redmine';
    var $request_format = 'xml'; // REQUIRED!
    var $element_name = 'issue'
}

   $issue = new Issue();
   $issues = $issue->find('all'); //Works fine
   print_r($issues);
```

The problem:

I want to get only issues that assigned_to_id is null, so I tried

```
$issues = $issue->find ("all", array('assigned_to_id'=>null)); //not working
$issues = $issue->find (false, array('assigned_to_id'=>null)); //not working
$issues = $issue->get ('by_assigned_to_id', array('assigned_to_id' => null)) //not working
```

None of these are working, what is wrong or what am I missing?

More reference: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess, but I wonder if you could pass a value of *. That's what I see in the url when I do a search for assigned to none.

```
$issues = $issue->find ("all", array('assigned_to_id'=>'*'));
```

Comment: That's not the solution, but thanks for helping. The problem here is because the field is null in database, the tag <assigned_to> in xml is not created when method find runs. I have tried to change it  in ActiveResource.php, but did not find where should I change. So I just call find('all') and loop all issues, if assigned_to is not set, that's the one I want. Not the best solution, but ok, it works...